# Does Ubuntu's 'Free software only' installation option still exist?

Tags: system-installation

Previous versions of Ubuntu Desktop had an installation option called "Free software only." Does this feature still exist in 21.10, or has it been removed?

"Free software only" option selection when installing Ubuntu Desktop 20.04:

[image: Ubuntu installation - free software only]

Comment: While I don't know the answer to this question (most likely, this option is still there), you may want to look into operating systems which only have free software in their repositories (the Ubuntu repository contains some non-free software for users' convenience). https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html

Comment: @archisman-panigrahi The installer for 21.10 looks slightly different from the one in 20.04 and does not show the screen in the picture but instead directly boots into a graphical menu asking whether you would like to try or install the OS.
Thank you for pointing me to the FSF's free/libre distros list; I'm aware of these concerns.

Comment: In 21.10, you probably need to press `Enter` right after it starts booting from the USB, to open this purple screen.